# dygraph charts in downloadHandler

Tags: r, download, dygraphs, gridextra

I am trying to get dygraph charts via downloadHandler into a PDF file and I am unabe to.  Not sure if it is because the gridExtra package is unable to handle html objects. Any help here is appreciated please.
To elaborate, please run the code below.  the first download tab, which is just for a ggplot object works as expected BUT the second download tab which is for dygraph object doesnt work.

```
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
library(htmltools)
library(gridExtra)

ui <- navbarPage(
  tabPanel(title = "Download",
           downloadButton("downloadcharts1"),
           downloadButton("downloadcharts2"),
           downloadButton("downloadcharts")
  )   
)


server <- function(input, output, session){
  
vals <- reactiveValues(p1=NULL, p2=NULL)

temperature <- ts(frequency = 12, start = c(1980, 1),
                  data = c(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 
                           25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6))
rainfall <- ts(frequency = 12, start = c(1980, 1),
               data = c(49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 
                        135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4))
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(temperature, rainfall))
g <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x=temperature, y=rainfall)) + geom_point()

g
g# create a normal plot object

vals$p1 <- g




# create a list of dygraphs objects

dy_graph <- list(
  dygraphs::dygraph(temperature, group="temp_rain", main="temperature"),
  dygraphs::dygraph(rainfall, group="temp_rain", main="rainfall")
)  # end list

# render the dygraphs objects using htmltools
dy_graph<- htmltools::browsable(htmltools::tagList(dy_graph))

vals$p2 <- dy_graph ## assiging to reactValues variable




output$downloadcharts1 <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function(){"chart1.pdf"},
  content = function(file){
    pdf(file, onefile=TRUE)
    grid.arrange(vals$p1)
    dev.off()
  }
)#download handler close

output$downloadcharts2 <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function(){"chart2.pdf"},
  content = function(file){
    pdf(file, onefile=TRUE)
    grid.arrange( vals$p2)
    dev.off()
  }
)#download handler close


output$downloadcharts <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function(){"charts1&2.pdf"},
  content = function(file){
    pdf(file, onefile=TRUE)
    grid.arrange( vals$p1, vals$p2)
    dev.off()
  }
)#download handler close




}


runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server), launch.browser=TRUE)
```

Comment: You cannot directly save htmlwidgets objects to pdf, they do not use R's graphics engine, They need to use a browser engine. You can save it to HTML but not pdf.

Comment: Thanks @Iz100 for the reply. I am using the HTML to combine multiple dygraph outputs into one here.  I suppose an alternative way to get the dygraph output into PDF (not necessarily via HTML) works for me fine actually.